# Why not the break order cannot stop the loop in my code?

Tags: python, loops, recursion

```
import os
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)

def searchFilePath(filename, path):
    try:
        for direction in os.listdir(path):
            if direction == filename:
                print(path)
                break
            elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, direction)):
                continue
            else:
                searchFilePath(filename, os.path.join(path, direction))
    except PermissionError:
        pass

searchFilePath("abc.rar", "d:\\")
```

Everytime the program found the target file, it could not stop immediately though I used break to end the recursion. It always went through all of the paths under the path then returned the result.

Comment: `break` stops *the current loop*, not any loops in progress in parent function calls.

Comment: You can't break out of recursion. Return the found value to stop recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` ends the *current loop only*. Any loops in progress further up in the call stack are not exited.

You'd have to return a flag from the function so a parent call can know to exit too:

```
def searchFilePath(filename, path):
    try:
        for direction in os.listdir(path):
            if direction == filename:
                print(path)
                return True
            elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, direction)):
                continue
            else:
                found = searchFilePath(filename, os.path.join(path, direction))
                if found:
                    return True
    except PermissionError:
        pass
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` leaves only the current loop. You have to use return value to signal the end of your recursion

```
def searchFilePath(filename, path):
    """ returns True if the filename was found in path """
    try:
        for direction in os.listdir(path):
            if direction == filename:
                print(path)
                return True
            elif not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, direction)):
                if searchFilePath(filename, os.path.join(path, direction)):
                    return True
    except PermissionError:
        pass
    return False
```

or if you want to use `path` further:

```
def searchFilePath(filename, path):
    """ returns the path, where the filename was found """
    try:
        for direction in os.listdir(path):
            if direction == filename:
                return path
            elif not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, direction)):
                found = searchFilePath(filename, os.path.join(path, direction)):
                if found is not None:
                    return found
    except PermissionError:
        pass
    return None
```

If you use `os.walk` you can simplify your function to:

```
def searchFilePath(filename, path):
    for path, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
        if filename in filenames:
            return path
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `break` wrong. `break` breaks you out of a single loop.

```
for x in some_list:
    for y in another_list:
        for z in yet_another_list:
            break
```

This will continue to loop through all values in `another_list`.

You want to use `return` which will break you out of the entire function.

```
for x in some_list:
    for y in another_list:
        for z in yet_another_list:
            return z
```

Note that this stops on the first iteration through `yet_another_list` and is only meant as an example as to why your code isn't working.